# OpenLayers 2 Prevent redraw of specific layer

Tags: openlayers-2

In a map with multiple layers I have one WMS-Layer I do not want to redraw on normal map-interaction (zoom, pan). I want to initiate the redraw after a XMLHttpRequest. How can I prevent the redraw for pan/zoom?

I was trying to remove the refresh-listener from the layer, but this has no effect. (I am not sure if this is useful in this context)

Looking into the source I have found the [OpenLayers.Map.moveTo()](https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Map.js#L1902) function. Is there a way to configure the layer, to be excepted in the moveTo()?